# Payment form submission is returning a curl error! ([curl] 3: <url> malformed [url])

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, payment-methods

I'm submitting a payment form via standard POST submission (not AJAX) to the current page URL, with an action value of `commerce/payments/pay`. To double-check my work, I've also copy + pasted their [example form](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-form-model), and I'm still getting the same result.

I've done this a thousand times before, so I'm going a bit crazy trying to figure out what's different in this project. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, here was the solution: The payment method for Authorize.net wasn't completely filled in; there was no endpoint set. Thus, it was of course failing when it sent the curl request, because there was no protocol, domain, or anything else other than the query string for the payment form.

Providing the payment method with an endpoint in the CP resolved this issue.